# Is there a "medium" \cap?

Tags: symbols, fontsize, math-operators

When displaying the intersection symbol in equations, e.g.,

```
$$Hom(A,B) \cap Hom(B,C)$$
```

I find that the "cap" is too small; its height is, in fact, subordinate to the surrounding content. On the other hand, `\bigcap` is entirely too big, dwarfing the surrounding content. This is especially unnecessary if the intersection is not indexed, for example. What is needed is a "medium" cap whose size is somewhere between the big cap and the regular cap. Does such a symbol/construct exist?

Note that similar comments apply to `\bigcup` and `\cup`.

Comment: You should use `\[ ... \]` for display math instead of `SS ... SS` as per [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: I've found that the size of `\bigcap` changes depending on whether you are inside `$`'s or `$$`'s.  It is smaller when you force it to be in-line with `$`'s.

Comment: Also, if you're writing text within math, use `\text{<text>}` from the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). If `Hom` is an operator (like `\sin`), use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}` and use `\Hom(A,B)`, or on-the-fly `\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)`, say. Both of the last commands are supplied by [`amsopn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsopn) (which is included when you load `amsmath`).

Comment: @jamaicanworm: This depends on the math mode you're in, apparently. `\bigcap` (and others) fall under the scope of "Variable-sized Math Operators" (see Table 57 on p 25 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `scalebox` from the `graphicx` package to create one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\medcap}{\mathbin{\scalebox{1.5}{\ensuremath{\cap}}}}%
\begin{document}
\[ Hom(A,B) \cap    Hom(B,C)\]
\[ Hom(A,B) \medcap Hom(B,C)\]
\[ Hom(A,B) \bigcap Hom(B,C)\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't find it to be too small. You can use the same symbol as `\bigcap`, but not in the "bigger" version, so there's some work to do:

```
\newcommand*\mcap{\mathbin{\mathpalette\mcapinn\relax}}
\newcommand*\mcapinn[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt
  \ifx\displaystyle#1\textstyle\else#1\fi\bigcap$}}}
```

This is the result of

```
\[\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\cap\operatorname{Hom}(B,C)\]
```

and of

```
\[\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\mcap\operatorname{Hom}(B,C)\]
```

You need `\usepackage{amsmath}` to use `\operatorname` and you might want to say

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
```

in the preamble, in order to be able to use `\Hom` as an abbreviation.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but found that the bottom of (in my case, the) medcup was too low. However, when I redefined to shrink from the bigcup at 85%, it looked just like I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scalerel` from the `scalerel` package to create one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[ Hom(A,B) \cap Hom(B,C) \]
\[ Hom(A,B) \scalerel{\cap}{Hom(B,C)} \]
\[ Hom(A,B) \mathbin{\scaleobj{1.75}{\cap}} Hom(B,C) \]
\[ Hom(A,B) \mathbin{\scaleobj{0.9}{\bigcap}} Hom(B,C) \]
\[ Hom(A,B) \bigcap Hom(B,C) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `\mathbin{\scalerel{\cap}}`, if you want correct spacing.

Comment: I am afraid not because `\scalerel` is a two arguments command.
Said that, it is true that the spacing is not correct.

Comment: Instead we can use `\scaleobj`. I added the corresponding material.

Comment: I hadn't thought of scaling down from the larger version. This worked well.