# Reduce size \bigcup

Tags: scaling

I want to reduce size `\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty`? How can I do it?

I tried `\newcommand*{\medcap}{\mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}{\ensuremath{\bigcap}}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippets compilable?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\scalebox{1}{...}` doesn't change the size.

Comment: it is rather unusual to change the size of individual characters, a font is designed as a coherent whole (ideally) so if neither `\cup` nor `\bigcup` are suitable perhaps you should be using a different font?

Comment: it would be easier to answer this question if you provided some context.  is this being used in text?  in display?  please provide a small compilable example that we can experiment with.

Comment: Look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38709/is-there-a-medium-cap

I want a "medium \cap (\cup)" with limits

Comment: $$\lambda\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_k\right)$$

$\verb| \lambda\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_k\right)|$ 
I want just to reduce

Comment: The brackets are massively oversized there (use `\bigl(` not `\left(` )  I wouldn't change the bigcup.

Comment: @Euler I added that example to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably simply use the smaller version available in the font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

zzz
\[
\bigcup_0^n > {\textstyle \bigcup\limits_0^n} > \mathop{\cup}_0^n
\]

\end{document}
```

with the example added in comments I would keep the standard bigcup but use more reasonable brackets

[image]

```
\[\lambda\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_k\right % no:-)
>
\lambda\Bigl(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_k\Bigr)
\]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want the symbol to have the same size in display style as in text style. The thread you link is for growing the symbol *bigger*.

The argument to `\reduceoperator` should be a comma separated list of *names* of operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reduceoperator}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\reduceoperator@\expandafter{\next}}%
}
\newcommand{\reduceoperator@}[1]{%
  \csletcs{normal@#1@}{#1@}%
  \csedef{#1@}{\noexpand\reduceoperator@@\csname normal@#1@\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand{\reduceoperator@@}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\reduceoperator@@@{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\reduceoperator@@@}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\fi#2%
}
\makeatother

\reduceoperator{bigcup,bigcap,bigotimes}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_{ij}\bigotimes_{k=1}^uB_k
\]
\begin{center}% to test inline math
$\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_{ij}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` or `\mathsmaller` from `relsize`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, relsize}

\begin{document}

\[ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\qquad \medmath{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty} A_n\qquad \mathsmaller{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]